# Split Top Level CIDR to to netmask length (to be used by nested object) - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, terraform, subnet

A netmask length is a number requested and provisioned into pool based off the top cidr range

Assuming I have a top_cidr = ["10.0.0.0/8"]

How do you split the cidrs to netmask_length and pass the values dynamically to other sub netmask_length based off the top_cidr

I need to make the netmask_length

```
module "basic" {
  source  = "aws-ia/ipam/aws"

  top_cidr = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  top_name = "basic ipam"

  pool_configurations = {
    corporate-us-west-2 = {
      description = "2nd level, locale us-west-2 pool"
    #   cidr        = ["10.0.0.0/16", "10.1.0.0/16"]
    netmask_length = ?

      sub_pools = {

        sandbox = {
          name                 = "mysandbox"
        #   cidr                 = ["10.0.0.0/20"]
        netmask_length = ?
          ram_share_principals = var.sandbox_ou_arn
          allocation_resource_tags = {
            env = "sandbox"
          }
        }
        dev = {
          netmask_length = 20

          sub_pools = {
            team_a = {
              netmask_length       = 24
              locale               = "us-west-2"
            }

            team_b = {
              netmask_length       = 26
            }
          }
        }
        prod = {
        #   cidr   = ["10.1.16.0/20"]
        netmask_length = ?
          locale = "us-west-2"

          sub_pools = {
            team_a = {
            #   cidr                 = ["10.1.16.0/24"]
            netmask_length = ?
              ram_share_principals = var.prod_account # prod account
            }

            team_b = {
            #   cidr                 = ["10.1.17.0/24"]
            netmask_length = ?
              ram_share_principals = var.prod_account # prod account
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    us-east-1 = {
    #   cidr   = ["10.2.0.0/16"]
    netmask_length = ?
      locale = "us-east-1"

      sub_pools = {

        team_a = {
        #   cidr                 = ["10.2.0.0/20"]
        netmask_length = ?
        }

        team_b = {
        #   cidr                 = ["10.2.16.0/20"]
        netmask_length = ?
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: IPv4 addresses are 32-bit unsigned integers. The dotted-decimal text notation only makes it easier for humans to read, but IP math needs to be performed on the integer value. Convert the text to integer values, perform the mat, then convert back to text. Remember that most prefix lengths are within an octet, not on an octet boundary. [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) gives you the algorithms for all the IPv4 math.

Comment: In [IPvX, my IP calculator](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX), I used the algorithms I described in the linked answer in above comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using  the [Terraform cidrsubnet function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/cidrsubnet) to calculate the subnet addresses. For example:

```
locals {
  top_cidr = "10.0.0.0/8"
}

module "basic" {
  source  = "aws-ia/ipam/aws"

  top_cidr = [local.top_cidr]
  top_name = "basic ipam"

  pool_configurations = {
    corporate-us-west-2 = {
      description = "2nd level, locale us-west-2 pool"
      cidr        = [cidrsubnet(local.top_cidr, 8, 0), cidrsubnet(local.top_cidr, 8, 1)]
    

      # The rest of your code
  }
}
```

I suggest opening the `terraform console` to play around with the `cidrsubnet` function to find the correct parameters you need to pass it to get the resulting CIDR blocks that you want to generate.

---

Alternatively if you want to pass the `netmask_length` parameters instead, which conflict with the `cidr` parameters, you could use a [CIDR Netmask calculator](https://mxtoolbox.com/SubnetCalculator.aspx) to figure out the values you need.

Terraform [has one of those](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/cidrnetmask) built-in as well, but it seems like your goal is to calculate the subnets dynamically instead of having them hard-coded in your Terraform template, and you would still have to hard-code them as arguments for the `cidrnetmask` function, so at that point it would be cleaner to just hard-code them directly as `cidr` parameters.